# smooth animate() of div on keydown()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, keydown

I'm trying to get a continuous movement for the div on keydown. The movement starts but then slows down and gets a bit jerky. How could I resolve this issue? here is my code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    width = $(this).width();

    switch(e.which) {
        case key.LEFT:
            $('.character').stop().animate({
                left:'-=' + width
            }, 2000);

            break;

        case key.RIGHT:
            $('.character').stop().animate({
                left:'+=' + width
            }, 2000);

            break;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
}).keyup(function() {
    $('.character').stop();
});
```

and here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yq2pgdx/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simply because you're using `animate()` and `stop()`. The `keydown` function fires once every time the UI is redrawn with a key pressed down; this is potentially hundreds or even thousands of times per second. Hence you were defining an animation and stopping it for each of those events.

A better approach would be to just add or subtract from the `left` position of the `.character` element each time the `keydown` event is raised. Something like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    width = $('.character').width();

    switch (e.which) {
        case key.LEFT:
            $('.character').css('left', function(i, v) {
                return parseInt(v, 10) - width;
            });
            break;

        case key.RIGHT:
            $('.character').css('left', function(i, v) {
                return parseInt(v, 10) + width;
            });
            break;
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4yq2pgdx/3/)

Also note that to get the width of the desired element in your delegated event handler you need to use the `.character` selector directly as `this` will refer to the `document`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. How could I go about making the movement not looking jumpy? instead making it continuous?

Comment: You could reduce the gap jumped on each keydown event: https://jsfiddle.net/4yq2pgdx/4/. It will always look relatively jumpy though, because you're at the mercy of the event detection rate of the browser.

Comment: @laurad if you're looking to program a sprite based game, it may be worth looking in to using a pre-existing framework, such as [Phaser](http://phaser.io/)

Answer (score 0):

As before mention, the stop() function is essentially stopping the animation.
you could simply try to remove it and the the time added in the
    https://jsfiddle.net/aluminium22/5uxwckz9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var key = {
        LEFT:37,
        RIGHT:39,
        UP:38
      };

      $(document).keydown(function(e) {
          width = $(this).width();

          switch(e.which) {
            case key.LEFT:
              $('.character').animate({
                left:'-=' + width
              });
              break;

            case key.RIGHT:
              $('.character').animate({
                left:'+=' + width
              });

              break;
          }

          e.preventDefault();
        }).keyup(function() {
          $('.character').stop();
        });
    });
```